# Save JSON details into Excel file using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading below json file and trying to store it in `.xlsx` format using pandas library of python.

JSON:

```
{ "log": [ 
 {
   "code": "info",
   "message": {"text": "[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule "},
   "refs": [{"href": "xule"}],
   "level": "info"
 }
,
{
   "code": "xyz.F1.all.7",
   "level": "error",
   "message": {
                "text": "[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114",
                "severity": "error",
                "cid": "63096080",
                "filing_url": "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd"
             },
   "refs": [
        {
         "properties": [
              [
               "label",
               "Megawatt hours sold, Sales for Resale"
              ],
              [
               "namespace",
               "http://xyzcom/form/2020-01-01/xyz"
              ],
              [
               "name",
               "ForResale"
              ],
              [
               "QName",
               "xyz:ForResale"
              ],
              [
               "contextRef",
               "c-177",
               [
                [
                 "entity",
                 "C002089",
                 [
                  [
                   "scheme",
                   "http://abcd.org/entity/identification/scheme"
                  ]
                 ]
                ],
                [
                 "startDate",
                 "2016-01-01"
                ],
                [
                 "endDate",
                 "2016-12-31"
                ],
                [
                 "dimensions",
                 "(1)",
                 [
                  [
                   "xyz:SalesForResaleAxis",
                   "<xyz:SalesForResaleDomain>0-3</xyz:SalesForResaleDomain>\n\t\t\t\t\n"
                  ]
                 ]
                ]
               ]
              ],
              [
               "unitRef",
               "u-03 (MWh)",
               [
                [
                 "measure",
                 "utr:MWh"
                ]
               ]
              ],
              [
               "decimals",
               "INF"
              ],
              [
               "precision",
               "None"
              ],
              [
               "xsi:nil",
               "false"
              ],
              [
               "value",
               "63"
              ]
             ],
         "href": "TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd#f-731",
         "objectId": "__91261",
         "sourceLine": 4114
        }
   ]
}]}
```

With following python code,

```
import json
import pandas
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

with open('C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/logfile_1.json', encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

flat = flatten_json(data)
normalizedjson = json_normalize(data)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('myDataFrame.xlsx')
normalizedjson.to_excel(writer, 'DataFrame')
writer.save()
```

I am able to create .xslx file with following format:
[image]

But, I want to create output in following format in Excel file which should have columns for - `code, message, refs and level`. And, Whatever values are under these keys in json should be respective row for each log.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1 = []
for i in range(len(data['log'])):
    code = data['log'][i]['code']
    message = data['log'][i]['message']
    refs = data['log'][i]['refs']
    level = data['log'][i]['level']
    data1.append((i,code, message, refs, level))

df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['log','code','message','refs','level'])

#op
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :)